# How to get hostname resolution for a virtual machine in UTM

Tags: network, dns, virtualization

I have installed a virtual Ubuntu Server on my M2 Mac using [UTM](https://mac.getutm.app/) (which seemed to be the most reliable Virtualization software supporting Apple silicon).

I only intend to connect to it using SSH. I can connect using it's IPv4 address, but I'd really like to be able to use the more friendly host name.

On the virtual machine, the host name is set to "ubuntu":

```
peter@ubuntu:~$ hostname
ubuntu
```

Connecting to "ubuntu" fails immediately. Connecting to "ubuntu.local" just hangs. But connecting to the IP address works.

```
❯ ssh -A peter@ubuntu
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ubuntu: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
❯ ssh -A peter@ubuntu.local
^C
❯ ssh -A peter@192.168.64.3
peter@192.168.64.3's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-91-generic aarch64)
```

How does host name resolution work on MacOS? I can see other Mac computers on the same net, connecting using the "hostname.local" scheme. What do I need to do to get this working for Linux?

Or is it because it's on a virtual network and a virtual network adapter created by the virtualization software, that the hostname doesn't work?

Comment: How is the the VM networked?  Is it NAT’d or bridged?  Either way, the easiest solution to this is to add the vm name and IP in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: @Allan As far as I can tell, the virtual machine is on a NAT network, with my Mac being the gateway (on another NAT). My primary network is on 196.168.7.x and the VM is on 196.168.64.x, so the VM is double NAT (which doesn't bother me for my purpose). I did think about the hosts file, if the VM IP is the same after a reboot, should be fine enough. I'd just rather want it to be automatic :D

Comment: The ubuntu.local should work - do you need to add bonjour to the VM? (I have only used ssh into macOS VMs which "just work")

Comment: @Allan does different networking modes have any advantages for this case? I wasn't presented with many options when creating the machine, but after shutting down, I can see that I can select from "Emulated VLAN", "Shared Network" (currently selected), "Host only", and "Bridged (advanced)".

Comment: Bridged allows you to make the vm a node on the same network as your Mac (192.168.7.x). You’ll also want to install, if not already, AVAHI mDNS client. If you got NAT, you’ll want to configure it with a static or reserved IP (in UTM’s DHCP server) so, you won’t lose the hostname/IP mapping in your hosts file. I

Comment: Alternatively, if the only thing you plan to do is SSH and SCP, make your IP static and just use an SSH config file with the name you’d like to use.